# Parsing dates in pandas dates columns

Tags: python, pandas

Good time a day to everyone.

Today i just started to study pandas.
Could you help me with parse dates in DataFrame, when data looks like this:
[image]

When i try to choose a column I got an error.
[image]

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: type chas.columns and look your column names

Comment: Index([                  0, 2020-02-01 00:00:00, 2020-02-02 00:00:00,
       2020-02-03 00:00:00, 2020-02-04 00:00:00, 2020-02-05 00:00:00,
       2020-02-06 00:00:00, 2020-02-07 00:00:00, 2020-02-08 00:00:00,
       2020-02-09 00:00:00, 2020-02-10 00:00:00],
      dtype='object')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your column header type to string with

```py
df.columns = df.columns.astype(str)
```

Then access one column with

```py
df['2020-02-01 00:00:00']
```